# How to use WinRT transitions for WPF 4

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-7, windows-runtime, wpf-4.0

I'd like to use the new metro transitions (AddDeleteThemeTransition, ContentThemeTransition, ...), for my WPF 4 project.

Can I use a dll ? Where could I download it ?

Comment: I suggest you to go through the following MSDN Article: [Quickstart: Animating your UI (Windows Store apps using C#/VB/C++ and XAML) (Windows)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh452703.aspx).
*Here you can also download a sample project to understand all this stuff better.* More References: [WinRT Transitions – Creating Fast and Fluid Metro UIs](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/269351/WinRT-Transitions-Creating-Fast-and-Fluid-Metro-UI) Hope this help.

Comment: Thx for help, but my application need a dll for this animations. I think it's in the GAC, but I don't have it with Windows 7 :/

Comment: oh!.. you should add windows 7 tag with your question also.. development environment should be mentioned for better help..

Answer (score 1):

WinRT/XAML is a different technology than WPF and none of its WinRT UI will work with WPF. Additionally these transitions seem to be using some different mechanism than regular Storyboards, so there is likely no way to just extract them to something that would work with WPF.

Your only option would be to implement something yourself and make it look good. Or alternatively give up support for Windows 7 and implement your application as a WinRT app for Windows 8.